# Regex in R: extract words from a string

Tags: r, regex

I have a string that I want to extract the names from, but I cannot seem to get everything right:

```
str = "JaMes + Heather + Lynn + log(Barry) + Sister2"
str_list = strsplit(x=str, split="\\+")
```

I do not wish "log(Barry)" as output, rather just "Barry".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to remove the `log` and the brackets with `gsub/sub`

```
gsub('log\\(|\\)', '', str)
#[1] "JaMes + Heather + Lynn + Barry + Sister2"
```

---

or with `sub`

```
sub('log\\(([^)]+)\\)', '\\1', str)
#[1] "JaMes + Heather + Lynn + Barry + Sister2"
```

---

Or with `regexpr/regmatches`, we can extract only the word

```
setdiff(regmatches(str, gregexpr('\\w+', str))[[1]], "log")
#[1] "JaMes"   "Heather" "Lynn"    "Barry"   "Sister2"
```

---

If we need the invididual words

```
library(stringr)
setdiff(str_extract_all(str, "\\w+")[[1]], "log")
#[1] "JaMes"   "Heather" "Lynn"    "Barry"   "Sister2"
```

Or use a regex lookaround

```
str_extract_all(str, "\\w+\\b(?!\\()")[[1]]
[1] "JaMes"   "Heather" "Lynn"    "Barry"   "Sister2"
```

Comment: Ah, and then I use strsplit afterwards, or?

Comment: @Helen Yes, that is a roundabout way, but a direct option is extraction

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_all_words(gsub("log", "", str))[[1]]
[1] "JaMes"   "Heather" "Lynn"    "Barry"   "Sister2"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take anything like `'function_name(object)'` and convert it to just `'object'` with `gsub`. After that, splitting on `' + '` will give the desired output.

```
strsplit(gsub('\\w+\\((.*)\\)', '\\1', str), ' + ', fixed = T)[[1]]
# [1] "JaMes"   "Heather" "Lynn"    "Barry"   "Sister2"
```